# Wikipedia-typed Django models relations

Tags: sql, django

I need to connect some articles where mentioned some people from another fields. For example, science, cinema, music, etc. How to build models in this situation, I'm sure, it is many to many relation, but how to control this third table and which data needed to connect? I need model, where will be name of article, text of article, field (cinema), and person (50 Cent). How to deal wit that fact, that one person may be related to several fields, for example, music and cinema?

Comment: For starters, you have to have data, and that what you have you should provide here. I don't see anything that can help me to answer your question.

Comment: Try looking up many to many relationships. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/